# Removing and installing Eclipse

Tags: pi-3

I have removed and purged Eclipse using

```
apt-get remove eclipse
apt-get purge eclipse
```

After typing in `eclipse`, I still get Eclipse splash screen. I waited for over five minutes to see if Eclipse will come up. It did not.

I went to GUI Add/ Remove software and found that Eclipse packages were still there. I marked them for removal and they were removed.

Terminal could not find Eclipse - good. There was no Eclipse under Programming menu - good.

In Terminal I did `apt-get install eclipse-cdt`.

It installed and can be executed, but it takes forever to come up. Probably because both Java and CDT packages are being loaded.

BUT - all I got, again, Eclipse (platform) 3.8 !

**I want the latest Eclipse Oxygen.**

How do I accomplish that? (What repository is this ancient Eclipse 3.8 coming from?) Currently running Eclipse "checking for software" but that did not pan in past attempts.

Comment: The 3.8 version is likely coming from the Raspbian repo. To get a more up to date version you will likely need to compile it from source. However, as you have already discovered this may be a fools errand; eclipse is known to be a resource hog and slow on even modern desktops with far more resources than are available on the Pi.

Comment: What do you mean "most likely"? This is digital world , it either comes from Raspbian or does not. After few weeks  using RPi ANY application is a challenge to its OS. I feel the real  fools are the folks who are repeating this "Elcipse" is a hog - it works as bad as any other app on RPi "limited resources.

Comment: You can add additional repositories, it is possible you added an additional repository - your question is unclear on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SteveRobillard is correct. The Eclipse version currently in the Raspbian repo is `3.8`. A quick Google search did not produce a repository that contains an Oxygen build for the RPi.

If you want to upgrade now, you'll need to download the source code from the Eclipse homepage and compile it yourself. If you want to do this on the RPi, this will take a very long time. You might want to look into cross compiling.

Comment: OK, but WHY using Eclipse to update itself get me numerous packages which cannot be installed because of missing dependencies?  Basically 3.8 cannot be updated and as far as RPi repository there is no newer version either. I can live with that, I am dropping the idea to develop C++ using Eclipse on RPi.